# exctract specific value from JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following problem. I want to extract the fields of "tracks" separately in this JSON file and make a dataframe. For example I want to make a column with the field pos, a field with the column artist_name, another column with track_uri etc but I get the following error for the field 'pos':

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15720/1561775056.py in <module>
     18 df3 = pd.json_normalize(js['playlists'])
     19 pd.options.display.float_format ='{:,.1f}'.format
---> 20 print(df5['tracks']['pos'])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    851 
    852         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 853             return self._get_value(key)
    854 
    855         if is_hashable(key):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
    959 
    960         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
--> 961         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
    962         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
    963 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    352                 except ValueError as err:
    353                     raise KeyError(key) from err
--> 354             raise KeyError(key)
    355         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    356 

KeyError: 'pos'
```

Here is the code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import os

path = 'C:\\Users\\sotir\\Desktop\\machinedataset'

filenames = os.listdir(path)
for filename in sorted(filenames):
    if filename.startswith("mpd.slice.") and filename.endswith(".json"):
        fullpath = os.sep.join((path, filename))
        f = open(fullpath)
        js = json.load(f)
        f.close()
df1= pd.json_normalize(js['info'])
df2 = pd.json_normalize(js['playlists'])
pd.options.display.float_format ='{:,.1f}'.format
df= df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
df3 = pd.json_normalize(js['playlists'])
pd.options.display.float_format ='{:,.1f}'.format
print(df3['tracks']['pos'])
```

[json file[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLiM7.png)]

[screenshot when I run df3.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnGlW.png)

Below is some of the data in the json file

```
{
    "info": {
        "generated_on": "2017-12-03 08:41:42.057563", 
        "slice": "0-999", 
        "version": "v1"
    }, 
    "playlists": [
        {
            "name": "Throwbacks", 
            "collaborative": "false", 
            "pid": 0, 
            "modified_at": 1493424000, 
            "num_tracks": 52, 
            "num_albums": 47, 
            "num_followers": 1, 
            "tracks": [
                {
                    "pos": 0, 
                    "artist_name": "Missy Elliott", 
                    "track_uri": "spotify:track:0UaMYEvWZi0ZqiDOoHU3YI", 
                    "artist_uri": "spotify:artist:2wIVse2owClT7go1WT98tk", 
                    "track_name": "Lose Control (feat. Ciara & Fat Man Scoop)", 
                    "album_uri": "spotify:album:6vV5UrXcfyQD1wu4Qo2I9K", 
                    "duration_ms": 226863, 
                    "album_name": "The Cookbook"
                }, 
                {
                    "pos": 1, 
                    "artist_name": "Britney Spears", 
                    "track_uri": "spotify:track:6I9VzXrHxO9rA9A5euc8Ak", 
                    "artist_uri": "spotify:artist:26dSoYclwsYLMAKD3tpOr4", 
                    "track_name": "Toxic", 
                    "album_uri": "spotify:album:0z7pVBGOD7HCIB7S8eLkLI", 
                    "duration_ms": 198800, 
                    "album_name": "In The Zone"
                }, 
                {
                    "pos": 2, 
                    "artist_name": "Beyonc\u00e9", 
                    "track_uri": "spotify:track:0WqIKmW4BTrj3eJFmnCKMv", 
                    "artist_uri": "spotify:artist:6vWDO969PvNqNYHIOW5v0m", 
                    "track_name": "Crazy In Love", 
                    "album_uri": "spotify:album:25hVFAxTlDvXbx2X2QkUkE", 
                    "duration_ms": 235933, 
                    "album_name": "Dangerously In Love (Alben f\u00fcr die Ewigkeit)"
```

Comment: where's df5? should it be df3?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected this but I get the same error.

Comment: you'll need to post some data please. use df3.head(10).to_dict() and paste it in to your question. no images please.

Comment: Ok I have included the json file and the df3 data

Comment: No images please. paste the actual data so it can be used by others to create a dataframe.

Comment: Ok I posted some of the data

Comment: Please add a self-contained example with a JSON that can be copy-pasted and that would represent your input data. Do you want to make a separate DataFrame for each playlist?

Answer (score 0):

I created a 2nd playlist and just changed the track positions. It sounds like you really want to take all the tracks information and create an expanded dataframe.

Here's the data:

```
js = {
    "info": {
        "generated_on": "2017-12-03 08:41:42.057563", 
        "slice": "0-999", 
        "version": "v1"
    }, 
    "playlists": [
        {
            "name": "Throwbacks", 
            "collaborative": "false", 
            "pid": 0, 
            "modified_at": 1493424000, 
            "num_tracks": 52, 
            "num_albums": 47, 
            "num_followers": 1, 
            "tracks": [
                {
                    "pos": 0, 
                    "artist_name": "Missy Elliott", 
                    "track_uri": "spotify:track:0UaMYEvWZi0ZqiDOoHU3YI", 
                    "artist_uri": "spotify:artist:2wIVse2owClT7go1WT98tk", 
                    "track_name": "Lose Control (feat. Ciara & Fat Man Scoop)", 
                    "album_uri": "spotify:album:6vV5UrXcfyQD1wu4Qo2I9K", 
                    "duration_ms": 226863, 
                    "album_name": "The Cookbook"
                }, 
                {
                    "pos": 1, 
                    "artist_name": "Britney Spears", 
                    "track_uri": "spotify:track:6I9VzXrHxO9rA9A5euc8Ak", 
                    "artist_uri": "spotify:artist:26dSoYclwsYLMAKD3tpOr4", 
                    "track_name": "Toxic", 
                    "album_uri": "spotify:album:0z7pVBGOD7HCIB7S8eLkLI", 
                    "duration_ms": 198800, 
                    "album_name": "In The Zone"
                }]},
                {
                    "name": "Throwbacks", 
                    "collaborative": "false", 
                    "pid": 0, 
                    "modified_at": 1493424000, 
                    "num_tracks": 52, 
                    "num_albums": 47, 
                    "num_followers": 1, 
                    "tracks": [
                        {
                            "pos": 2, 
                            "artist_name": "Missy Elliott", 
                            "track_uri": "spotify:track:0UaMYEvWZi0ZqiDOoHU3YI", 
                            "artist_uri": "spotify:artist:2wIVse2owClT7go1WT98tk", 
                            "track_name": "Lose Control (feat. Ciara & Fat Man Scoop)", 
                            "album_uri": "spotify:album:6vV5UrXcfyQD1wu4Qo2I9K", 
                            "duration_ms": 226863, 
                            "album_name": "The Cookbook"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "pos": 3, 
                            "artist_name": "Britney Spears", 
                            "track_uri": "spotify:track:6I9VzXrHxO9rA9A5euc8Ak", 
                            "artist_uri": "spotify:artist:26dSoYclwsYLMAKD3tpOr4", 
                            "track_name": "Toxic", 
                            "album_uri": "spotify:album:0z7pVBGOD7HCIB7S8eLkLI", 
                            "duration_ms": 198800, 
                            "album_name": "In The Zone"
                        }]}
                ]}
```

You can additional elements to the list (3rd argument, or remove altogether)

```
pd.json_normalize(js['playlists'], 'tracks', ['name', 'collaborative'])

   pos     artist_name                             track_uri                             artist_uri                                  track_name                             album_uri  duration_ms    album_name        name collaborative
0    0   Missy Elliott  spotify:track:0UaMYEvWZi0ZqiDOoHU3YI  spotify:artist:2wIVse2owClT7go1WT98tk  Lose Control (feat. Ciara & Fat Man Scoop)  spotify:album:6vV5UrXcfyQD1wu4Qo2I9K       226863  The Cookbook  Throwbacks         false
1    1  Britney Spears  spotify:track:6I9VzXrHxO9rA9A5euc8Ak  spotify:artist:26dSoYclwsYLMAKD3tpOr4                                       Toxic  spotify:album:0z7pVBGOD7HCIB7S8eLkLI       198800   In The Zone  Throwbacks         false
2    2   Missy Elliott  spotify:track:0UaMYEvWZi0ZqiDOoHU3YI  spotify:artist:2wIVse2owClT7go1WT98tk  Lose Control (feat. Ciara & Fat Man Scoop)  spotify:album:6vV5UrXcfyQD1wu4Qo2I9K       226863  The Cookbook  Throwbacks         false
3    3  Britney Spears  spotify:track:6I9VzXrHxO9rA9A5euc8Ak  spotify:artist:26dSoYclwsYLMAKD3tpOr4                                       Toxic  spotify:album:0z7pVBGOD7HCIB7S8eLkLI       198800   In The Zone  Throwbacks         false
```